# Auto installing of all package dependencies

Tags: r

So, I have an R package `x` on github that I am installing.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("bla/bla")
```

The installation fails (see error printout below). Package `x` has a few dependencies including `ggplot2`. All dependencies of `x` are installed automatically including ggplot2, but a package `scales`, a dependency of ggplot2 was not installed. Therefore, it failed. So, dependencies of dependencies are not automatically installed.

In my description file, I use 'Depends' for ggplot2. I noticed in the ggplot2 description file that `scales` is under 'Imports', rather than 'Depends'.

I know I can fix all this my just manually installing `scales`, or manually installing dependent dependencies. But, is there a way to automatically install all dependencies? 'Depends' and 'Imports'? Or am I missing something?

See console print out below:

```
Installing 1 package: Cairo
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/Cairo_1.5-9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1026234 bytes (1002 KB)
downloaded 1002 KB

package ‘Cairo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\rmf\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Eaf5a\downloaded_packages

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\rmf\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Eaf5a\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: gridExtra
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gridExtra_2.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 483300 bytes (471 KB)
downloaded 471 KB

package ‘gridExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\rmf\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Eaf5a\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: gtable
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gtable_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 57807 bytes (56 KB)
downloaded 56 KB

package ‘gtable’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\rmf\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Eaf5a\downloaded_packages
Installing 1 package: tidyr
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/tidyr_0.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 860798 bytes (840 KB)
downloaded 840 KB

package ‘tidyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\rmf\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Eaf5a\downloaded_packages
"C:/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/rmf/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8Eaf5a/devtools2fe8287648ea/royfrancis-test-4d3547f" --library="C:/R/R-3.3.3/library"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'x' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'scales'
Error : package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'x'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.3.3/library/x'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Session info

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1    R6_2.2.0      tools_3.3.3   withr_1.0.2   curl_2.5      memoise_1.0.0
[7] git2r_0.18.0  digest_0.6.12
```

Comment: You are simply doing it wrong.  A *package repository* (as in CRAN, or done with drat or one of the other repo-creating tools) *has* dependencies.  A random GitHub *code repo* does not.  What I do in a situation like this is to _create a package_ which I then place _into a package repository_.

Comment: I thought installing using `install.packages()` from CRAN or `install_github()` from devtools both install dependencies simply because of the contents in the description file. Just to clarify, my package x is not just random R code, it has a proper R package structure, so it should in theory install like a normal R package.

Comment: Just to clarify: it is _not your package_ but where you are installing it from. Just wishing that a _GitHub code repository_ actually were an _R package repository_ does not make it so.  You need create a package repository.  Which is both trivial and why I wrote drat to help.

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1370